# Migrate TFS 2008 to Visual studio online? (on build and security)

Tags: visual-studio

we uses on-premise tfs 2008 for source safe and build engine. The build script is heavily customized with msbuild scripts. Developers uses active directory to authenticate then queue a build.

We look around to go to Visual Studio Online, question
- the big concern is the build script, we don't really want to rewrite it, is it possible to use the current MSBuild project in the VSO build process?
- for authentication, how to integrate with the on-premise AD with the VSO? how to migrate the existing security project settings to the VSO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the answers to all of your questions is maybe .

You can continue to use your on-premises build server with VSO. If you upgrade your agents to TF Build 2010 or 2013 servers you can plug them into VSO and build in the same way.

You may be able to use the cloud build agents if you don't need custom things installed on the build agents to compile. Probably best to stick with local agents for now.

For AD you can configure an Azure Active Directory (AAD) and wire it up to VSO. There is then a connector to sync your local AD with AAD (very easy) and enable single signe-on. There are fiddly bits but mostly strait forward.

http://nakedalm.com/use-corporate-identities-existing-vso-accounts/

I enabled it for my account but without the local AD sync as I don't have one.

I have a few customer that are on VSO and sync their local AD with AAD and are very happy.

Comment: thanks!! for the build part, just to confirm, we can still use the msbuild on the .proj file right?

Comment: Yes - even better support in 2015